# Crear WaterMark usando Php Office/php word

Tags: php

Que tal muy buenas tardes,estoy tratando de  agregar una imagen de fondo para cada una de las paginas creadas  en  mi archivo word,usando la librería php office/phpword,el archivo lo genero con código solo no puedo agregar una marca de agua,¿Existe alguna manera de realizar esto?

Comment: ¿Has intentado ponerlo como fondo en la cabecera? Deberías poner lo que hayas intentado para que podamos verlo y así ayudarte mejor. Lee [ask] para más información. Saludos.

Comment: Y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general.

Comment: Ya lo puse como  fondo en la cabecera pero solo me aparece  en la parte superior,pero yo quiero que aparezca en el centro de cada pagina, mi codigo es el siguiente